# Admob legacy to New Admob in eclipse

Tags: admob

Can you help me with replacing my old legacy code to the new admob?  I have a pretty easy way I did it before using the xml files in layout.

1 Do I still have to use this link or what is the new reference: xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"

2 Do I simply replace the add unit below with the actual new one?

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="a11111111111b"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

1. What happens to this code?

   ```
   <activity
       android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
       android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
   ```

I would really appreciate some help here because for some reason my eclipse keep asking for updates and at the moment everything seems to be a nightmare.

THANK YOU in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The XML namespace for the Google Play Services version of Admohb is `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`
2. There is a new AdView class in the GPS version of Admob that you should use. It is `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView`
3. Again there is a new AdActivity class `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity`

Comment: Hi William Thank you so much. Guyes like you should make some tutorials and just offer it for a small fee :-)  This whole new admob has really gotten me confused and now eclipse is giving problems too, so I am truly greatful for your answer.  Thanks alo.